How to remove duplicate elements from a slice of slices in golang
i have a function which returns a slice of slices.
[[-1 -1 2] [-1 0 1] [-1 0 1]]
Trying one way of map method wont work because slice cannot be a key. How do i remove the duplicate elements here.

For the future, do tell how much data can be involved. If its only a few elements then the dumbest and simplest code is fine whereas if its tens of thousands or more elements, the choices become a little more limited and if its in the millions then even more limited. Given the example data I would myself probably just create a second slice and only copy over elements if they are not already present. Don't remove, just "not add".

Also, to add to blackgreens answer, deduplication without changing the order (Go Playground):
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "slices"
)

func ExampleDedup() {
    s := [][]int{{-1, 0, 1}, {-1, -1, 2}, {-1, 0, 1}}
    s = Dedup(s)
    fmt.Println(s)
    // Output: [[-1 0 1] [-1 -1 2]]
}

func Dedup[S ~[][]E, E comparable](s S) S {
    d := s[:0]
    for _, dd := range s {
        if !slices.ContainsFunc(d, func(e []E) bool { return slices.Equal(e, dd) }) {
            d = append(d, dd)
        }
    }

    return d
}

This has runtime O(n^2), so it's bad for big slices, but should be fine for small slices, like in your example.

Use slices.CompactFunc where you can supply your own function to test for equality of slice elements. Or you can use slices.Equal from the same package.
import (
    "fmt"
    "slices"
)

func main() {
    s := [][]int{{-1, -1, 2}, {-1, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, 1}}
    s = slices.CompactFunc(s, slices.Equal)
    fmt.Println(s)
    // [[-1 -1 2] [-1 0 1]]
}

Note that slices.Compact and slices.CompactFunc deduplicate consecutive identical elements.
If the duplicate elements are not consecutive, sort the slice first, as shown in this post. You can tweak it for sorting slices using slices.Compare:
import (
    "fmt"
    "slices"
)

func main() {
    s := [][]int{{-1, 0, 1}, {-1, -1, 2}, {-1, 0, 1}}
    slices.SortFunc(s, slices.Compare)
    s = slices.CompactFunc(s, slices.Equal)
    fmt.Println(s)
    // [[-1 -1 2] [-1 0 1]]
}

